# Black screen after GRUB

Tags: grub2

Good afternoon.
First of all, sorry for my english, i know it's not the best you have ever read.
This morning I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I was trying playing a little with its configuration (preferences, nothing else) ans downloading some programs, trying to programm with the terminal and stuff.

When, a few minutes ago, I wanted to re-start Windows, I found that I couldn't.

I get to GRUB, everything than expected and I have 5 options (I'm writting from memory, because I have not noted them):

- Ubuntu
- Additionals options for Ubuntu
- Memory Test
- Another memory test (advance maybe?)
- Windows (loader) on /dev/sda1

I choose the last option y it goes into Windows, or I thought so. The fact is that after GRUB disappeared, I left a black screen and the top lines begin to appear as distorted colors (if it's important I can take a picture with the phone and upload it) that does not extend to rest of the screen, there are 1 cm or something like that.

I don't find the solution nowhere because of everything I found is related to problems with GRUB does not appeared or something.

I leave the report of a sudo fdisk -l command on a Ubuntu terminal, hoping it can help:

---

```
Disco /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 121601 cilindros, 1953525168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x25233875

Dispositivo Inicio Comienzo Fin Bloques Id Sistema
/dev/sda1 * 2048 206847 102400 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2 206848 1245448800 622620976+ 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3 1245450238 1953523711 354036737 5 Extendida
La partición 3 no se inició en el limite físico del sector
/dev/sda5 1245450240 1936783359 345666560 83 Linux
/dev/sda6 1936785408 1953523711 8369152 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disco /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 8570 MB, 8570011648 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 1041 cilindros, 16738304 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x9e01f612

El disco /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 no contiene una tabla de particiones válida
```

---

I hope you can help me, i would be so grateful.

Greetings.

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't know that I could use format.
I'm having problems with Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7.

Result for cat `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=es_ES
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
}
submenu 'Opciones avanzadas para Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.8.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-advanced-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        fi
        echo    'Cargando Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Cargando el disco RAM inicial...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.8.0-19-generic (modo recuperación)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-recovery-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        fi
        echo    'Cargando Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Cargando el disco RAM inicial...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (en /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D87A07D87A07B274' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  D87A07D87A07B274
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D87A07D87A07B274
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Result for `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=es_ES
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
}
submenu 'Opciones avanzadas para Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.8.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-advanced-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        fi
        echo    'Cargando Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Cargando el disco RAM inicial...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, con Linux 3.8.0-19-generic (modo recuperación)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-recovery-fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
        fi
        echo    'Cargando Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Cargando el disco RAM inicial...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fb3c5402-5a59-4e52-99ea-b81b9c9c1586
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (en /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D87A07D87A07B274' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  D87A07D87A07B274
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D87A07D87A07B274
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
alberto@alberto-P67A-D3-B3:~$ ^C
alberto@alberto-P67A-D3-B3:~$ clear

alberto@alberto-P67A-D3-B3:~$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Edit your question and add some info. Boot into Ubuntu open a terminal and issue these commands one at time. `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `cat /etc/default/grub` . Post the results here. Edit your question and add the results in code sample please. <$>

Comment: It could also be useful to know which version of Windows it is that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Edited and added extra information.

Comment: I assume from you question that you are able to boot into Ubuntu. I suggest you try installing [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), a crafty little program that is able to identify and correct most of common GRUB problems. If you can't boot into Ubuntu, use a live CD to do it.

Comment: I have done it. Now GRUB have a extra option, Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Both Windows option go to the black screen.
The report from the Boot-Repair is in:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5933155/

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair is saying file system is unclean. Did you resize Windows from the installer? And was Windows hibernated?
After any resize of the NTFS partition Windows needs to run chkdsk. I would run that from your Windows repairCD or flash drive or some third party Windows repairCD that have chkdsk.
If you had Windows hibernated you need to remove hiberfile and run chkdsk.

Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/