# Can't install Kubuntu 18.04 on a ASUS FX503VD gaming laptop

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, 18.04, laptop, asus

I have searched many topics online, and followed instructions for how to install on high-end ASUS gaming laptops, yet Kubuntu 18.04 LTS fails to install.

Kubuntu just never loads, and goes to a black screen no matter what I add after the word splash (when pressing 'e' in grub).

I have to go now, but I will be back later and add more info that may help.
Just so you know things I have tried, yet are not working for me.  Links:

- [Asus FX503VD Elan1200 Touchpad not working smoothly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981183/asus-fx503vd-elan1200-touchpad-not-working-smoothly)
- http://pclub.in/2017/01/06/Linux-on-Asus-ROG.html
  This one seems to have worked for a few people, but I can't even get it installed in the first place.

Comment: ChaletOS isn't supported here. So please keep that in mind when you get around to editing your post.

Comment: Are you able to use a LiveUSB with Kubuntu and boot, not install? You may also find helpful this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/327009/black-screen-after-grub

Comment: Yes, ChaletOS support is at http://chaletos.4rumer.com/t237-install-chalet-os-with-uefi , http://chaletos.info , https://unix.stackexchange.com/ , or https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/108630943169932456503 . There's so much to do to support Ubuntu and its flavors that we have to focus on it to the exclusion of other Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

My model is GL503VD and I just now managed to install 18.04 by doing nothing but as follows:

1. Deleting `---` or `$vt_handoff` parameters right after `quiet splash`
2. After deleting the above adding `acpi_osi=!` parameter right after `quite splash`
3. boot

Going by [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:ASUS_E403SA) it seems that there is an unresolved driver issue with trackpad and or backlight with this laptop model and Ubuntu 18.04.